# extract power plans from saved registry

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I need to restore Windows 7 power plans. I saved full registry on an old PC (also Windows 7), that PC is not available any more. **How can I extract power plans from the saved registry?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Extract registry branches `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power` and `...\ControlSet001\...` from the full registry saved--use any text editor
2. Run regedit, [take ownership and change permissions to Full Control for yourself](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/cannot-import-registry-file-getting-error-cannot/1bd7f5fd-e37e-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=f57411dc-8a7f-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) for each of `...\ControlSet00{1|2}\Control\Power` branches and all its childs
3. Import registry branches `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00{1|2}\Control\Power` with `regedit` or `reg` (failing to do so result in "Cannot import file: ... Error accessing the registry" reported by `regedit`).
4. Reboot Windows (failing to do so results in "Your power plan information isn't available" when opening any of power plans)

*(Note that* `...\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power` *is filled up automatically with one of* `ControlSet00X`*, so you don't need to extract or import it)*